# Sort mails in Gmail from a mailing list after certain buzzwords

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

My problem: I get lots of mails from a mailing list. Let's call it `list@gmail.com`.

I am not in all of them interested and I want to filter them. 
Mails that are coming via this list@gmail.com AND containing in the body text OR in the subject line certain buzzwords word1 word2 word3 should get one label1.
All other emails, going to this mailing list, but containing not these buzzwords, neither in the text OR in the subject, should get another label2. 
I don't want any crossover.

My first try:
I set up the filter in gmail's filter mask. Not sure if the single fields are connected by an AND or an OR. As far as I know, curly brackets mean OR.

1. Filter:
   to: list@gmail.com
   includes_the_words: {Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}
2. Filter:
   to: list@gmail.com
   subject: -{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}
   includes_the_words: --{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}

It does not work. So far, emails arriving via the list@gmail.com are now in the INBOX.

If it matters, Filter1 is above Filter2 in the hierarchy of Gmail's filter list.

Answer (score 1):

*include_the_words* is not a valid Gmail search operator by the other hand  there should not be a space between the search operator and the keyword. Instead of

```
to: list@gmail.com includes_the_words: {Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}
```

try

```
to:list@gmail.com {Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}
```

instead of

`to: list@gmail.com subject: -{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"} includes_the_words: --{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}`

try

`to:list@gmail.com subject:-{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"} {Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}`

Reference

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: Re includes_the_words : I know, but it appears in the drop down mask as "includes the words" under the subject field. It is probably called hasTheWord: (XML file)  I just wanted to indicate that I search the text body of the email, hence I copied the name of this field. In the end I put everything in this drop-down-mask in the filter tab
I did basically what you suggested.
Is there a mistake in your last line? Should it not be to:list@gmail.com subject:-{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}  -{Word1 Word2 Word3 "Long Word4"}
I do not want the Word1 in the subject, neither in the text body